# How to make ellipsize work across multiple lines?

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

Hi guys I am trying to make ellipsize work over 2 lines but I'm not sure how to...currently it's working but it cuts it of after one line. Any ideas?

```
var recipeName = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            color:'#576996',
            font:{fontSize:Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth*5/100,fontWeight:'bold', fontFamily:'Arial',textAlign:'center'},
            left:Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight /5 + 20,
            top: 0,
            right: 5,
            height: photo.height /2.5 , 
            width:Ti.UI.FILL,
            clickName:'user',
            ellipsize:true,
            wordWrap : false,
            verticalAlign: 'TEXT_VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT_TOP',
            text: results.matches[c].recipeName
        });
```

Comment: As you are setting a fixed height, the label might be too small. Try setting `height: Ti.UI.SIZE` and see if it is formatted correctly.

Comment: I've tried making the height massive and it is still on one line. I tried Ti.UI.SIZE as well and it still was only showing it on one line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try twi things:
1. add singleline false
or 
2. create custome class for textfield